# Strategy pattern executing two or more algorithms

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

Can anyone make me an example of a strategy pattern that use not one, but two or more algorithms in sequence??

Maybe have I to insert those algorithms in a list and then with a for execute all algorithms in this list?

This list must be a public attribute of context class?

Please, can anyone make me a pseudo-code example?

Comment: sounds like homework to me. what have you tried?

Comment: I'm not interested in a solution, I want to understand how to act in these cases. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Are you bound to use a strategy or could you also use the other patterns you wrote on another comment?

Comment: the strategy is only my hp . give a look down the page, i wrote the concrete problem

Comment: maybe you should add those to your question.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement a strategy, which invokes all algorithms in specific order. My example is linked with classes described in [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

```
class MultiAlgorithm implements Strategy {

    private Strategy[] strategies;

    public MultiAlgorithm(Strategy... strategies) {
        if (strategies == null || strategies.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Algorithms collection cann't be null!");
        }
        this.strategies = strategies;
    }

    @Override
    public int execute(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("Called MultiAlgorithm's execute()");
        int result = 0;
        for (Strategy strategy : strategies) {
            result += strategy.execute(a, b);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Example of usage

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Context context = new Context(new MultiAlgorithm(new Add(),
            new Multiply(), new Subtract()));
    int result = context.executeStrategy(1, 2);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

As you see, we must only implement new "complicated strategy". Pattern himself stayed without changes.

Comment: many thx mykhaylo. 

Just some question : 
1) why you declare private Strategy[] strategies; in every concrete strategy and not ,for example in the context??
2) int result = context.executeStrategy(1, 2); what is the meaning of a and b variables?

Comment: 1. I don't want to change pattern. Adding new "complex" strategy is simpler for me ;) And I don't declare it in every concrete strategy - I declare it only in this one. You could use it in creation process for bigger algorithms 2. This is just an example - implementation of Multi Algorithm could be without sense - but imagine situation where we must to calculate sum of : a + b, a * b, a - b.

Comment: Thanks for your patience,  can you explain how can I iterate over the private Strategy[] strategies if it is defined  private in the class? I do not understand

Comment: You invoke the executestrategy method of the instance the context was created with and it executes all of the other strategies

Comment: Because we iterate over the collection in this concrete implementation. We don't need to change the Context class, because we can create the strategy which can do it for us. Why should we change the context? We can create one complex strategy, which launch other strategies in specific order.

Comment: good morning first of all :) .

If I understand it, the class MultiAlgorithm contains all the algorithms of noise removal?

Comment: Yes, it can contains all algorithms. It depends only from you - you can create instance of the class with the number of algorithms which you want. You can provide all algorithm or only few.

Answer (score 1):

You could just have an implementation of your strategy that was a composite of two instances of your strategy which were executed in sequence couldn't you?

Although I can't think of a situation in which this would be useful.

Exactly what you want to do is not clear.

** based on your comments below  **

I don't think the strategy patten is appropriate here as you are always doing a fixed thing,  applying all the implementations of noise filters that you have, and the strategy pattern is for choosing between different approaches. You only have 1 strategy!

I would implement this as a processing pipeline. Create the pipeline with all algorithms you know about at the start in the order you want to apply them. In the run method invoke the pipeline which in turn invokes each of the algorithms in turn.  As New events are raised by system to say a new processor is available, add it to the pipeline.

**edit2**

You could probably implement it using the observer pattern (though not a great fit imho) if the object with the run method is the subject in the pattern and when new processors are added the addsubscriber method is called to add the processor to the list. Then when run is called you iterate the list of subscribers and pass them the sound to modify.

But that feels all sorts of wrong to me.

Comment: this is an example of use : 

I got 3 algos called a , b , c and a context. now i want to call a-b-c in sequence on che context. 

so .. my idea is : 
declare a public list in context . 
Declare a method in interface_strategy called :add_strategy_to_list().
In concrete_strategy class implement add_strategy_to_list() in order to add the strategy to the list .

Comment: The strategy patten usually selects 1 strategy from a list, based on some criteria. Something other than the class implementing the strategy decides on the strategy to use. If you want to chain them together so they all get a chance to run, and each one decides of it should process the given content then you are better with a chain of responsibility

Comment: If you want all of them to run but them to be unaware of each other or the caller to be unaware the the decorator might be more appropriate

Comment: yes. The problem is that i can only use one or more between : Singleton, composite,observer,mediator, adapter,factory,strategy,bridge,iterator.

Comment: Without more context is difficult to say, but it sound like you might want a composite  algorithm. You need to show what you have tried and clarify what you are trying to do

Comment: I have to build a system to remove noise from audio files.

The system provides several techniques for noise removal.

the system has a method "run ()" which allows you to launch the removal of noise () on the audio file, applying in sequence all the techniques available at the time.

The system must notify the addition of new techniques of noise removal to be able to invoke this with the other.

Comment: Yeah, @SamHolder is right: what you are describing is not Strategy.

Comment: Yes,but for my bad luck this exercise is on design patterns from the ones I listed earlier.Infact My difficoult is about choose between these design patterns

Comment: yes, i'm thinking in term of observer just now . but it is not a   "clean" solution.

Comment: Maybe the purpose of the task is for you to tell your tutor that none of the patterns you are allowed to use are suitable ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what your assignment is trying to get at is that you have some outer code (perhaps a controller) that has to decide at runtime which approach to use to handle something. Quite often this is done with Strategy: the handlers are all implementations of the Strategy (in Java, this is an interface), and then you could either hold them in a map where you dispatch the appropriate one based on something like the type of the incoming request, or you could hold them in a list and loop through them and find the one that's suitable.

If you let everyone just get a crack at handling the message, you have a Chain of Responsibility.